# tidb - how to solve node_exporter up timeout

Tags: tidb

I get this output when using tidb node_exporter up:

```
fatal: [tidb@172.17.3.226]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 309, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for search string 200 OK in tidb@172.17.3.226:9100"}
fatal: [tidb@172.17.3.225]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 309, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for search string 200 OK in tidb@172.17.3.225:9100"}
fatal: [tidb@172.17.3.227]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 309, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for search string 200 OK in tidb@172.17.3.227:9100"}
fatal: [tidb@172.17.3.228]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 309, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for search string 200 OK in tidb@172.17.3.228:9100"}
```

How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure firewalld service is stopped or you have opened the tcp/9100 port on your target servers.
2. check if node_exporter process is running (ps -ef | grep node_exporter)
3. check if node_exporter service is healthy (curl http://172.17.3.226:9100/metrics)